# How to detect 3rd party adserver requests

Tags: javascript, flash

I run video ads on my site. I've been trying to detect ad clicks on my video ads. I would like help detecting clicks on the videos/ rich media ads (3rd party)

So the video ads are flash videos.
Here is an example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vaunit_unit_type=0;
var vaunit_width=300;
var vaunit_height=250;
var vaunit_id=4320;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://syndication1.viraladnetwork.net/getad/"> </script>
```

I would really appreciate any help at all. Even if it's a link or a search keywork

Answer (score 0):

The Flash video isn't part of the browser; the browser mainly leaves space empty on the page and then tells Flash the boundaries of the empty area. When the video is rendered, Flash will create a new window in that empty area which is why the browser can't detect any mouse events inside of that window as soon as it gets the focus (i.e. when you click inside of it).

This is why you can't put an element in front of a Flash video (like an invisible `div`): The Flash window is on top of the browser window; the browser can always only render "below" it.

So to do what you want, you will need the source code of the Flash video player. That will allow you to add mouse listeners and detect mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickcount=0;

$( 'div #videospace a' ).click(function() {

clickcount=clickcount+1;

    });
```

Add this in another script tag its a solution of your problem you will get click count from **clickcount** var as if you diagnose your add iframe having  clicable link which shows the add with popup is under din with  id="videospace"

if you want click on advertiser and publisher are also counts then add one more function with it

```
  $( 'div #directlinksa' ).click(function() {

    clickcount=clickcount+1;

        });
```

Comment: let me know its wors for you or not